Python: Can not connect to cataloged db2 database (ibm_db)
System
OS: Fedora 40
Kernel: 6.10.6-200
Installed DB2 client: v11.5.9_linuxx64_client.tar.gz
python 3.12.5
ibm_db 3.2.3

The environment variables are set
$DB2INSTANCE     db2inst1
$DB2_HOME        /home/db2inst1/sqllib
$IBM_DB_HOME     /home/db2inst1/sqllib
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64/gskit:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib32

I have cataloged the connection
db2 "catalog tcpip node <NODE> remote <HOST> server <PORT> remote_instance <INSTANCE>"
db2 "catalog database <DB> as <DB> at node <NODE> authentication SERVER_ENCRYPT"

Test: I can connect via db2 connect to <DB>
Here comes the python part
I followed the instructons from https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=db-connecting-database-server
import ibm_db
conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=<DB>;HOSTNAME=<HOST>;PORT=<PORT>;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=<USER>;PWD=<PASS>", "", "")

This solution works, but I want to use the cataloged connection
import ibm_db
conn = ibm_db.connect("<DB>", "<USER>", "<PASS>")

Now i get the following error
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1531N  The connection failed because the name specified with the DSN connection string keyword could not be found in either the db2dsdriver.cfg configuration file or the db2cli.ini configuration file.  Data source name specified in the connection string: "<DB>". SQLCODE=-1531

How can I fix this?
(I have already uninstalled ibm_db and reinstalled it again)

Supplement 1
Thanks @mao
I don't want to create and edit db2dsdriver.cfg manually, because other applications use the cataloged db2 connections. An so it is not practical to edit the connection Informations twice.
But generating the db2dsdriver.cfg file with the db2dsdcfgfill command is a option.
To generate the db2dsdriver.cfg I followed these instructions:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=file-data-server-driver-configuration-location
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=file-db2dsdcfgfill-create-configuration
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=dsdcf-copying-existing-database-directory-information-into-db2dsdriver-configuration-file
db2dsdcfgfill -i db2inst1 -o /home/db2inst1/sqllib/cfg

SQL0000W  Die Anweisung konnte fehlerfrei verarbeitet werden.

When I search for the file db2dsdriver I only get db2dsdriver.xml and db2dsdriver.cfg.sample but not db2dsdriver.cfg.
I searched inside the three db2dsdriver.xml files but did not find my cataloged connections.
find / -type f -name "db2dsdriver*" 2>/dev/null

/home/<USER>/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/clidriver/cfg/db2dsdriver.cfg.sample
/home/<USER>/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/clidriver/cfg/db2dsdriver.xsd
/home/<USER>/git/<PYTHON_PROJECT>/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/clidriver/cfg/db2dsdriver.cfg.sample
/home/<USER>/git/<PYTHON_PROJECT>/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/clidriver/cfg/db2dsdriver.xsd
/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/cfg/db2dsdriver.cfg.sample
/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/cfg/db2dsdriver.xsd

What did I do wrong?

Supplement 2
I executed th command with the user db2inst1 and the file was created
db2inst1@<MACHINE>:~$ db2dsdcfgfill -i db2inst1

SQL1535I  Das Dienstprogramm db2dsdcfgfill hat die Konfigurationsdatei db2dsdriver.cfg erfolgreich erstellt.

The following file was created /home/db2inst1/sqllib/cfg/db2dsdriver.cfg
Then I changed the group and permission on the file so that I can use the db2dsdcfgfill command with my user.
After that I had to create a symbolic link
ln -s /home/db2inst1/sqllib/cfg/db2dsdriver.cfg /home/<USER>/git/<PYTHON_PROJECT>/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/clidriver/cfg/db2dsdriver.cfg                                                            

Now I can connect in python via
import ibm_db
conn = ibm_db.connect("<DB>", "<USER>", "<PASS>")

This solution works, but is not very pretty. Is there a more elegant way?

This is configuration work, as distinct from programming.
You are using clidriver, as per the message .
Clidriver parses db2dsdriver.cfg and / or db2cli.ini (not the catalog).
You only need one of these files to be configured.
The more modern file is db2dsdriver.cfg while db2cli.ini  is legacy.
You can create the db2dsdriver.cfg in the clidriver cfg subdirectory (by default no such file exists).
It is an XML file , you can either edit it with a text editor ,or use command lines to add or delete entries, see the online Db2 knowledge centre for details.
IBM gives a sample XML file in the clidriver cfg subdirectory. The Db2 knowledge centre gives details of the file and its content.
With the full Db2 client, there's also a tool to fill the db2dsdriver.cfg from the catalog, see docs db2dsdcfgfill.
With python ibm_db, you either have the DB connection details in python(full connection string), or externally in one of these files. No other option currently. Automation can help keep such files maintained. Note also environment variable DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH

Thanks @mao. I tried db2dsdcfgfill but without luck. I have edited my initial question
